# C++ select only range of char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

Is possible to select a few chars from array ?

Like :

```
std::string(charArray from 0 to 16)
```

Without this process :

```
char chName[16];

for(int i = 0;i<16;i++)
{
    chName[i] = decrypted[i];
}

std::string characterName(chName);
```

Comment: Look at the [`std::string` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), I'm sure you can find something there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to construct and initialize a `std::string` with an already existing char buffer, you can simply use the appropriate constructor:

```
std::string characterName(decrypted, 16);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::string::substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/).

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string str = "hello world";
    std::string cut_str = str.substr(0, 3);
    std::cout << cut_str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code will print "hel".

Answer (score 1):

I presume that what you are saying is you have a char array of size `X` of which you want to create a string from the first `Y` bytes, where `Y`<`X` then you either need to create a string of the whole thing and use `.substr(0,Y)` or do something like

```
char x = source[Y];
source[Y]='\0';
std::string out(source);
source[Y]=x;
```

which avoids the loop, but is nasty in its own way.